# Notation "name: " vs ":name => "

Tags: ruby, syntax, hashrocket

I'm not too clear what's the difference between the follwing two notations:

```
= render :partial => "order_fields", :locals => { :t => type, :f => c}
= render :partial => "order_fields", :locals => { t: type, f: c}
```

They both seem to work but I can't understand what's the difference. Could you please help me?

Comment: The second line will work only in ruby 1.9 and up.

Comment: I don't currently do Rails, but I suspect the `=` at the start of the two lines are erb stuff, not Ruby.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No difference. The latter is a new hash syntax in ruby 1.9.

(*Why do I still call this "new syntax"? Ruby 1.9 is 4 years old, and it's not even the current version :)*)

Comment: Yes @priti, both are same. you should have ruby 1.8 and 1.9 installed in your system and open your irb, than start playing with these hashes.

Comment: @RailsGuy: no need for ruby 1.8. Ruby 1.9 is enough. It supports both syntaxes.

Comment: yeah @Sergio, I know that, But to whom It was concerned, have already removed her comments..